# Getting new symbols into Mathematica

Tags: symbols, fonts, keyboard

What is the easiest way get new symbols into *Mathematica 9*?
For example I want to be able to write the Symbol

```
\mathfrak{A}
```

that you have in *Latex*.

I know that you can simply write an "A" in the notebook and change the font, so you get the right symbol. But this way you have to change between the font-window and the notebook window, and find the right font for your purpose.

Favourably I would like 
to set a new pallet
or integrate the symbol in the aliases
or set a shortcut like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for the symbol above

I already tried to change the fonts of *Mathematica* generally, so that the Symbol produces by  "<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>" changes to `\mathfrak{A}` in *Latex*, but did not get any satisfying result.

Answer (score 6):

You already have a palette for a great variety of symbols used in math.  Just go to Palettes -> Special Symbols.  The palette contains the $\mathfrak{A}$ symbol as well.

You can also enter it using <kbd>esc</kbd> goA <kbd>esc</kbd>, which stands for *Gothic A*.  If you enter  symbol using a palette, you can search for it in the docs to find out the shortcut.

Take a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html).

Comment: My pallet does contain the Gothic A "" you posted. When I enter "esc A esc" i do get a letter that fits the style of "" but does not look quiet the same. I also could not find the letter anywhere else in the documentation center.

Comment: Maybe there are missing some fonts? Is there a font package to install to get these Symbols?

Comment: esc A esc will give you a capital alpha, not a Fraktur style A.  esc goA esc will give you a Fraktur A.  It will not be identical to the one you have in LaTeX, but it will be similar.  It's a different font.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to type an $\mathfrak{A}$ that is 100% identical to the one you get in LaTeX?  That might not be easy or convenient.

Comment: sry I meant to write esc+goA+esc. Yep thats what I meant. I want to write exactly the Symbol you get in latex when you write the command \mathfrak{A} so this .

I already tried to just change this letter in the MathematicaFonts.dfont file, you find in

/Applications/Wolfram CDF Player.app/SystemFiles/Fonts/TrueType

but could not create the format .dfont because my skills in fondforge are not really good.

Comment: With: "might not be easy or convenient" you mean, that there is no way to just change the font for "math cells"??

Comment: @nickel Trying to replace the fonts of Mathematica is a bad idea, it'll just break the system.  Of course you can change the font of a single letter easily, just select it and use Format -> Show Fonts...  That won't change the meaning of the letter though just the appearance.

Comment: Jep. In the post at the very beginning I posted that doing it this way makes it very hard to write, so I am looking for a way to either do it with a new created pallet, an aliases way like esc+goA+esc or with a shortcut like cmd+shift+A. I need this special letter and an other one pretty often, so It is very annoying to change between the font window and the notebook window for each letter.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the A in gothic fonts, located at

/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Fonts/TrueType/MathematicaFonts.dfont
,

with the A from the latex fonts and it does produce one error message:

INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: SpanBox|c|2178
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
Mathematica by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

I can live with that since I am only using mathematica to write at the Moment.
Since it is only necessary to replace one family of fonts i can just copy the default family back to its original location to get the old letters.